# Difference Between DHL (Deprecated) and DHL Shipping Method

Tags: magento-1.9, dhl

I have DHL Details for Shipping Method.

In admin Showing Two DHL shipping Methods DHL (Deprecated) and DHL.

So Please Suggest me Which one I should Configure.

Comment: I would say the one that's not deprecated, but I don't have an explanation for it.

Comment: I Thought also Same But I Need to  Know Difference Between Them.

Comment: Any Suggestion Please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the release of Magento CE 1.8.1, a new DHL Shipping Method started to be used, but the old one (DHL Deprecated) is still available in the admin panel.

This [link here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ce1.8_release-notes.html) explain how to use the DHL Deprecated if you want to. (The page is big, so search for "deprecated" or go to the section "Changes in this release").

I would suggest you to use the new DHL method since is the newer version. I am not sure about the "code" differences in the backend, but this is the one supported by Magento now (the deprecated was removed from their manual) as you can see in [this link](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/sales/shipping-methods.html)